# Jq - print in one line values from different keys

Tags: arrays, sorting, search, replace, jq

Sample Json file:

```
[
    {
        "Header": {
            "Tenant": "Test-d1",
            "Stage": "dev",
            "ProductType": "b2b",
            "Rcode": 401
        },
        "Body": {
            "error": {
                "code": 401,
                "message": "Unsupported authorization scheme"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Header": {
            "Tenant": "2734d7ac0f0e",
            "Stage": "unknown",
            "ProductType": "unknown",
            "Rcode": 404
        },
        "Body": {
            "error": {
                "code": 404,
                "message": "Not found"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Desired output:

```
Test-d1, dev, b2b, Unsupported authorization scheme, 401
2734d7ac0f0e, unknown, unknown, Not found, 404
```

So skip the keys, interested only with certain values and form a single line, separate them by commas or semicolumn or some other separator.

The simplest procedure I could imagine with jq was to put values into an array and use @csv

```
jq  -r .[] | [ .Header.Tenant, .Header.Stage, .Header.ProductType, .Body.error.message, .Body.error.code ] | @csv
```

Above *almost* does what I wanted, but encloses every value with double-quotes. I can deal with double-quotes using some other tools but I'm sure it should be possible within jq itself.

What are alternative approaches using jq?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@csv` is guaranteed to produce CSV, but if you want strings to be presented unconditionally without the surrounding quotation marks, you could consider using `join(", ")` instead of `@csv`. Since you indicated you're open to some other value-separator, you might also wish to consider `@tsv`.

The redundancy in the jq program can also be reduced, so you might end up with:

```
.[] 
| (.Header     | [.Tenant, .Stage, .ProductType]) + 
  (.Body.error | [.message, .code ])
| @tsv
```